# Can I Store and Execute Desktop Applications in/from Cloud Drives?

Tags: google-drive

Specifically, I want to know if I can store a full, executable copy of the free Code::Blocks (CB) program in Google Drive (GD) so that I can run the program on any computer, not just my home computer.

In a more generalized context, I would also like to know if any full programs (word processors, games, art/music editors, etc.) can be stored in any cloud storage locations (GD, OneDrive, iCloud, etc.) - for instance, if there was a preventative problem with specifically GD, I still want to know if this can be done with another cloud service.

I attempted to store CB in GD, but discovered that it only saved a .lnk file, which I discovered was the web-equivalent of a Shortcut (a LiNK). Clicking on it, the prompt asked whether I wanted to download or connect to more apps. When I searched through Google and the SuperUser forums, the topics I discovered dealt primarily with storing files and whether or not you could sync an external hard drive with a network drive, but these do not answer my question, as I specifically want to know whether an application can be saved in and executed from GD (or any other drive), and if so, how.

If it makes a difference, this question is also not solely for backup purposes--it is not enough to be able to save the full application in cloud storage, but answering this question also requires answering whether the application can be executed from the cloud storage location without downloading an additional copy to the hard drive of the computer from which the cloud storage is being accessed.

Comment: There are lots of reasons this will probably not work, and will definitely fail in all but the most perfect of situations.  first, understand that the code that makes up a program must be loaded into ram before it can execute, so you are in fact downloading the file to a temp location, executing it, and then deleting the local copy when you are done. Programs often link to system/shared libraries, which must also be copied down and loaded, but the pathing semantics will fail because the cloud drive doesn't have a traditional path. stick to portable versions of apps, as your first rule.

Comment: Yes;  You can upload portable applications to Google Drive and have access to the portable application on any computer where you sync your Google Drive to.  I have mounted my Google Drive, and then launched applications, from the mounted drive